# Importing Excel data with merging cells

Tags: python, excel, pandas

**How we can import the excel data with merged cells ?**

[Please find the excel sheet image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5FcAz.png).

Last column has 3 sub columns. How we can import without making changes at excel sheet ?

Comment: Not a `machine-learning` question, kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

```
# Store data in variable
dataset = 'Merged_Column_Data.xlsx'

# Import dataset and skip row 1
df = pd.read_excel(dataset,skiprows=1)

    Unnamed: 0    Unnamed: 1    Unnamed: 2  Gold    Silver  Bronze
0   Great Britain        GBR          2012    29        17      19
1   China                CHN          2012    38        28      22
2   Russia               RUS          2012    24        25      32
3   United States         US          2012    46        28      29
4   Korea                KOR          2012    13         8       7

# Create dictionary to handle unnamed columns
col_dict = {'Unnamed: 0':'Country', 'Unnamed: 1':'Country',
            'Unnamed: 2':'Year',}

# Rename columns with dictionary
df.rename(columns=col_dict)


          Country   Country Year    Gold    Silver  Bronze
0   Great Britain       GBR 2012      29        17      19
1           China       CHN 2012      38        28      22
2          Russia       RUS 2012      24        25      32
3   United States        US 2012      46        28      29
4           Korea       KOR 2012      13         8       7
```